# "iconv.h: No such file" while trying to install Python Package

Tags: python, windows, command-line, gnu, iconv

I am a Windows user but I wanted to use the [`iconv`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.1.html) Linux command line, used in order to convert file from one encoding to an other. Moreover, I wanted to use this in one of my Python 2.7 program.

So I found [this package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iconv/1.0).

Using the *cmd* Command Prompt and after solving the [`"Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558328/2291710) (VS 2013) issue, I now have an error message saying:

`iconvmodule.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iconv.h': No such file or directory`

Can someone explain to me how to fix this please?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should compile `libiconv` library first. `iconv.h` lives in `libiconv`.

The guide is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/302012/How-to-Build-libiconv-with-Microsoft-Visual-Studio).

Comment: I followed the tutorial carefully but I have yet compilation errors (`missing ')' before '('` line 47 for example, among others). Too bad, I'll try something else. Thank you anyway for taking the time to help me.